# Android Parallax Image

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, parallax

I would like to create an animation in one of my activities that, when a button is clicked, the background "moves" to the next section of an image. A very good example of this is how Expedia Android app does this for creating a user. When create an expedia account is selected, the background animates to another section of the background image.

Any help on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated! [image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done extending viewPager. Take a look at some of the github libraries for demo :

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/ParallaxPager

https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerTransformer

https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax

https://github.com/garrapeta/ParallaxViewPager

https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager

Comment: Trying out solutions, will respond soon

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success using this library:

https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager

Instead of changing the background when scrolling, I make it change when a button is clicked.